# R Shiny include html embed excel doesn't show on Chrome

Tags: r, excel, google-chrome, shiny

I set up a R Shiny app on the server which has a panel embedding an Excel spreadsheet in it. The embedded excel can show up in IE browser but it doesn't show up in Chrome. I've turned ad blockers off and tried a few other options I'm aware of, but got no luck.

Wondering if anyone knows why this is happening.

The script of embedding the excel spreadsheet is simply

```
tabPanel("Master Model", includeHTML("include.html"))
```

where include.html includes the embed code for the excel spreadsheet with details below:

```
<iframe width="1800" height="900" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/..."></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you please share the code of `include.html` and your shiny code? That will help others to understand your problem.  [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is your version of Chrome? Recently I had a somehow similar issue with some recent versions. That works in Chromium and Vivaldi, but not in Chrome. Though my issue is not really the same, it is some html not displayed in an iframe.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent it should be a pretty recent version of Chrome. My concern is also about iframe.

Comment: @AdagioMolto The html is added in the original post.